# Order of execution in promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a sample program to understand how **`promises`** and **`async/ await`** works. But am a little bit confused about the execution order of promises. Can anybody explain how this works?

## CASE1

```
//Promise 1
let promiseTest = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var k = 0;
  for(i=0; i< 1000; i++ ){
    k += i;
  }
  resolve(k);
  console.log("Inside promise1")
});

promiseTest.then((res)=> {
    console.log('Promise1 result : '+ res);
}).then(() => {
    promiseTest2.then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    });
}).then(finish)
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err)
});

//Promise 2
let promiseTest2 = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Inside promise2")
});

function finish(){
    console.log("finished promise");
}
```

For this am geting the result as

## RESULT

```
Inside promise1
Inside promise2
Promise1 result : 499500
finished promise
```

## CASE2

I have another example doing the same with async/ await. But in this order of execution is correct.

```
//Async await test
async function AsyncTest(){
    console.log("Inside async1")
    var k = 0;
    for(i=0; i< 1000; i++ ){
      k += i;
    }
  console.log('async1 result : '+ k);
  const result =  await AsyncTest2();
  console.log(result)
  console.log("finished async");
}

async function AsyncTest2(){
   return "Inside async2";
}

AsyncTest();
```

## RESULT

```
Inside async1
async1 result : 499500
Inside async2
finished async
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't *return* the second promise from the callback, so it's not part of the same chain.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you correct the part where am doing wrong?

Comment: `return promiseTest2.then(...)`

Comment: ok, cool am corrected it. and it's working in correct order. So what it makes difference for both cases?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `.then(cb)` on a Promise, a new Promise gets created and returned by it, that will resolve to whatever the callbback *returns*. If that is a Promise itself, that Promise will be awaited before the chain continues. In your case you did:

```
promiseTest.then((res)=> {
 console.log('Promise1 result : '+ res);
 return undefined; // implicit return
}).then(() => {
 /* doesnt matter what you do here */
 return undefined;
}).then(finish)
```

Wether you attach another `.then` to another promise does not matter to this chain of promises.

Comment: So what is the difference between both method? Is both are working in the same format?